# CORS Error when moving Angular Spring Boot Applcation

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

So I am working on a web app however I'm having issues when I'm moving everything from local host to a domain I have hosted. Currently whenever I try to any post requests to my back end I get the following error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://sweatguild.com:8080/api/auth' from origin 'http://sweatguild.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I did some looking around and found that running the following command allows the post requests:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

but obviously this is not optimal.

Here is some of the relevant code

**Where the post request is being made in angular:**

```
getUserDetails(charName: string, password: string){
    return this.http.post('http://sweatguild.com:8080/api/auth', {
      charName,
      password
    }).subscribe(data =>{
      if(data){
        this.loggedInStatus = true;
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'true');
        localStorage.setItem('charName', charName);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
        this.getPerms(charName);
      }else{
        this.loggedInStatus = false;
        localStorage.removeItem('charName');
        localStorage.removeItem('loggedIn');
        localStorage.removeItem('admin');
        window.alert("Incorrect login information");
      }
    })
  }
```

**In Spring Application**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://sweatguild.com:80")
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class RosterController {
    @Autowired
    RosterRepository rosterRepository;

    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public boolean loginAuth(@RequestBody Roster roster){
        System.out.println(roster.getCharName());
        return rosterRepository.loginAuth(roster);
    }
```

Again all of this was working when I had it working on localhost. Any and all ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CORS will be raised if your two process running on different port tries to communicate on single server.

When you try to connect from local to remote API, it works as these 2 process running on different machine.

You don't need to add `@CrossOrigin` annotation if your angular and spring boot code is in same jar/build. If those are running on different port make sure you added correct angular app process port in CrossOrigin annotation.

If you mentioned correct port number then try to add allowed method types too like:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://sweatguild.com:<ANGULAR_APP_PORT>", methods = {RequestMethod.POST})
```

Or simply allow all origins like:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
```